# Matrix vector multiplication where the vector has been interpolated - Python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, finite-element-analysis

I have used the finite element method to approximate the laplace equation [image: $-u_{xx} = sin(\pi*x)$] and thus have turned it into a matrix system AU = F where A is the stiffness vector and solved for U (not massively important for my question).

I have now got my approximation U, which when i find AU i should get the vector F (or at least similar) where F is:

[image]

AU gives the following plot for x = 0 to x = 1 (say, for 20 nodes):

[image]

I then need to interpolate U to a longer vector and find AU (for a bigger A too, but not interpolating that). I interpolate U by the following:

```
U_inter = interp1d(x,U)
U_rich = U_inter(longer_x)
```

which seems to work okay until i multiply it with the longer A matrix:

[image]

It seems each spike is at a node of x (i.e. the nodes of the original U). Does anybody know what could be causing this? The following is my code to find A, U and F.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy
from scipy.sparse import diags
import scipy.sparse.linalg
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Poisson_Stiffness(x0):
    """Finds the Poisson equation stiffness matrix with any non uniform mesh x0"""

    x0 = np.array(x0)
    N = len(x0) - 1 # The amount of elements; x0, x1, ..., xN

    h = x0[1:] - x0[:-1]

    a = np.zeros(N+1)
    a[0] = 1 #BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
    a[1:-1] = 1/h[1:] + 1/h[:-1]
    a[-1] = 1/h[-1]
    a[N] = 1 #BOUNDARY CONDITIONS

    b = -1/h
    b[0] = 0 #BOUNDARY CONDITIONS

    c = -1/h
    c[N-1] = 0 #BOUNDARY CONDITIONS: DIRICHLET

    data = [a.tolist(), b.tolist(), c.tolist()]
    Positions = [0, 1, -1]
    Stiffness_Matrix = diags(data, Positions, (N+1,N+1))

    return Stiffness_Matrix

def NodalQuadrature(x0):
    """Finds the Nodal Quadrature Approximation of sin(pi x)"""

    x0 = np.array(x0)
    h = x0[1:] - x0[:-1]
    N = len(x0) - 1

    approx = np.zeros(len(x0))
    approx[0] = 0 #BOUNDARY CONDITIONS

    for i in range(1,N):
        approx[i] = math.sin(math.pi*x0[i])
        approx[i] = (approx[i]*h[i-1] + approx[i]*h[i])/2

    approx[N] = 0 #BOUNDARY CONDITIONS

    return approx

def Solver(x0):

    Stiff_Matrix = Poisson_Stiffness(x0)

    NodalApproximation = NodalQuadrature(x0)
    NodalApproximation[0] = 0

    U = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(Stiff_Matrix, NodalApproximation)

    return U

x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
rich_x = np.linspace(0,1,50)
U = Solver(x)
A_rich = Poisson_Stiffness(rich_x)
U_inter = interp1d(x,U)
U_rich = U_inter(rich_x)
AUrich = A_rich.dot(U_rich)
plt.plot(rich_x,AUrich)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you amend your code so that it is runnable standalone? Also, I don't see any interpolation part in your code (`interp1d`), where is that?

Comment: Hi i've now included my code and the program used to find the plot (including my use of interp1d), thank you

Comment: WIth a minor indentation correction, this code is complete - it runs with a simple cut and paste.

Comment: If you use a different interpolation method it seems to work. Try 'kind='cubic'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment 1:

I added a `Stiffness_Matrix = Stiffness_Matrix.tocsr()` statement to avoid an efficiency warning. FE calculations are complex enough that I'll have to print out some intermediate values before I can identify what is going on.

comment 2:

`plt.plot(rich_x,A_rich.dot(Solver(rich_x)))` plots nice. The noise you get is the result of the difference between the inperpolated `U_rich` and the true solution: `U_rich-Solver(rich_x)`.

comment 3:

I don't think there's a problem with your code. The problem is with idea that you can test an interpolation this way. I'm rusty on FE theory, but I think you need to use the shape functions to interpolate, not a simple linear one.

comment 4:

Intuitively, with `A_rich.dot(U_rich)` you are asking, what kind of forcing `F` would produce `U_rich`.  Compared to `Solver(rich_x)`, `U_rich` has flat spots, regions where it's value is less than the true solution.  What `F` would produce that?  One that is spiky, with `NodalQuadrature(x)` at the `x` points, but near zero values in between.  That's what your plot is showing.

A higher order interpolation will eliminate the flat spots, and produce a smoother back calculated `F`.  But you really need to revisit the FE theory.

You might find it instructive to look at

```
plt.plot(x,NodalQuadrature(x))
plt.plot(rich_x, NodalQuadrature(rich_x))
```

The second plot is much smoother, but only about 1/5 as high.

Better yet look at:

```
plt.plot(rich_x,AUrich,'-*')  # the spikes
plt.plot(x,NodalQuadrature(x),'o')  # original forcing
plt.plot(rich_x, NodalQuadrature(rich_x),'+') # new forcing
```

In the model the forcing isn't continuous, it is a value at each node.  With more nodes (`rich_x`) the magnitude at each node is less.

Comment: Hi, Thanks alot for the reply it's well put. The necessity for the interpolation comes from dual weighted residual error estimation as i'm trying to find error indicators; eta_i = (f[i] - sum_j( A[i,j]U[j] ) )z[i] where f, A and z are all evaluated over the richer mesh and U[j] is evaluated over the smaller mesh then interpolated. My problem is that for some reason the error indicators stop decreasing after about 4 iterations and thus i end up with meshes like the following:

Comment: [ 0.          0.11111111  0.22222222  0.33333333  0.44444444  0.5
  0.55555556  0.61111111  0.63888889  0.65277778  0.65972222  0.66319444  0.66493056  0.66579861  0.66623264  0.66634115  0.66644965  0.66666667  0.77777778  0.88888889  0.94444444  0.97222222  1.        ] I.E all grouping around the same error indicator as it has stopped decreasing

Comment: Those comments will read better if added to the original question (marked as added or edit).